Emojis not rendering with colors
I am trying to add COLOR emojis onto images as overlay, but it seems like the emojis keep being rendered in black and white, and also transparent:

This is what I'm currently working with:
def add_text_overlay(image_path, text, font_path, emoji_font_path, font_size, text_spacing, x_padding, output_path,
                     text_position, offset_x, offset_y):
    with PILImage.open(image_path) as img:
        img = crop_and_resize(img, 1080, 1440)

        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, font_size)

        # Load the emoji font using PIL
        emoji_font = None
        try:
            emoji_font = ImageFont.truetype(emoji_font_path, 137)  # Adjust pixel size as needed
        except OSError as e:
            logging.error(f"Unable to load the emoji font: {e}")
            logging.error(f"Path checked: {os.path.abspath(emoji_font_path)}")
            emoji_font = font  # Fallback to regular font if emoji font fails

        lines = wrap_text(text, 28)
        fixed_line_height = font_size + text_spacing
        total_text_height = fixed_line_height * len(lines)

        initial_text_y = (img.height - total_text_height) / 2 + offset_y

        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            text_bbox = draw.textbbox((0, 0), line, font=font)
            text_width = text_bbox[2] - text_bbox[0]

            if text_position == 'left':
                text_x = x_padding + offset_x
            elif text_position == 'right':
                text_x = img.width - text_width - x_padding + offset_x
            else:
                text_x = (img.width - text_width) / 2 + offset_x

            text_y = initial_text_y + i * fixed_line_height
            if text_x < 0:
                text_x = 0
            if text_x + text_width > img.width:
                text_x = img.width - text_width

            # Draw each character with the appropriate font
            for char in line:
                char_font = emoji_font if is_emoji(char) else font  # Use emoji font for emoji characters
                draw.text((text_x, text_y), char, font=char_font, fill="black")
                text_x += char_font.getbbox(char)[2]  # Update this line to use getbbox

        img.save(output_path)

I was having "invalid pixel size" error for a while until I changed the pixel size to 137. then afterwards it just drew the monochrome transparent emoji.

It's going to depend on the capabilities of your output device.

Looks like you are missing embedded_color=True in draw.text. See this answer.

Are you sure the font in question has color emoji?

it will depend on the default presentation of the emoji, and whetehr you are using variation selectors. It wll depend on the font, it may also depend on the opentype features you enable, and more importantly for Pillow, it will depend on whether you have libraqm and all its dependencies such as harfbuzz installed.
